# JSON Column: Index was out of range

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-core-8.0

I have a problem when doing a JSON COLUMN with EF. What I tried to achieve is `JobDetails` column in my SQL Server to store a bunch of JSON with dynamic of field, but those field later will be filter a column `Team` so that the deserializer know what to do. Below are my line of code that I've been tried.

`DataContext.cs`

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<JobHistory>()
        .OwnsOne(b => b.JobDetails, o =>
         {
           o.ToJson();
         });

    OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
}
```

`JobHistory.cs`

```
public partial class JobHistory
{
    [Key]
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    public string? Team { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public JobDetails? JobDetails { get; set; }
    public int? IsActive { get; set; }
}

public class JobDetails
{
    public List<TeamA>? TeamA { get; set; }
    public List<TeamB>? TeamB { get; set; }
}
```

`JobService`

```
public async Task AddJob(JobHistory jobHistory)
{
   try
   {
      _data.JobHistory.Add(jobHistory);
      await _data.SaveChangesAsync();
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {

   }
}
public async Task<List<JobHistory>> GetAllJob(string team)
{
   try
   {
      var jobs = await _data.JobHistory
           .Where(j => j.Team == team && j.IsActive == 1)
           .ToListAsync();
           return jobs;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      return new List<JobHistory>();
   }
}
```

From those approach I keep getting an error for both saving a data and tried to retrieve it

> {"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')"}

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you _wanting_ to actively violate the principles of normalized database design by doing this?

Comment: `catch(Exception ex) {}` <-- Please don't do this. This will only cause things to break and leave you with no idea of what's going on. Only catch exceptions you can gracefully handle.

Comment: Hi @Dai, honestly I also questioned my self what kind of design I want. If you have a suggestion I would like to consider and implement it based on what I tried to achieve. `Team` properties later will add up from time to time that's the main concern for me

Comment: Whats your requirement? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I tried to store all the `Team` properties in a column `JobDetails` in the database. Those Team will have a different field suit to their requirement. My requirement is that when the user from those Team able to see their history based on the Team they assigned. I also have an admin role that able to see all the history.

Comment: `Index was out of range` ... The first couple lines of the stack trace would narrow this down.

Comment: To be honest storing data in this way is bad normalization. You should only use JSON where the type/shape of the data is variable, not where it's just to store foreign key data, which should be stored in  rows in a separate table.

Comment: Hi @Charlieface any recommendation design for my case?

Comment: Like I said, normalize it into a separate table `JobHistoryTeam ( JobId, TeamId, PRIMARY KEY (JobId, TeamId) )` or some such